# Matplotlib not importing correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm on Windows using Python version 3.4.2. My Matplotlib is not importing in my file when I run it in the cmd, but it seems to work when I import from the python shell. I'm not sure if my path is messed up somehow. Whenever I run it in the cmd, it produces the following error:

```
F:\pypractice> py montecarlo.py
Traceback (most recent call last>:
  File "montecarlo.py", line 2, in <module>
     import matplotlib
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Again, it works in the python shell, so it probably is a PATH problem. The path I have in my environment variables is F:\Python34\;F:\Python34\Scripts\; I was told to install the following modules: numpy, pyzt, dateutill, setuptools, and six. This fixed the importing error in the python shell.

All of my modules are placed in F:\Python34\Lib\site-packages.

Any help with fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that regular executable `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: It's a regular executable PATH.

Comment: Then you are messing with the wrong variable. Please update the question with `PYTHONPATH` (if this doesn't already resolve it).

Answer (score 0):

I was messing with the wrong variable. Simply placing     #!/usr/bin/env python at the top of my file fixed the problem.